# Clipping in the desired shape

Tags: polygon, clip, arcgis-10.5, polygon-creation

[image]I am trying to use the clip tool in order to clip a bigger polygon with a smaller one. The thing is that the clip tool gives as an output a small area from the intersection of the two mentioned. I want to have a polygon that this area will be subtracted...

Comment: What about the [Difference](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#difference)? Are you working with QGIS? Please add a corresponding tag

Comment: could you tell us witch software you use and what exact tool with witch setting ? Also a picture coud help to see what is wrong

Comment: Hi everyone.. Thanks for your answers. I am working with ArcGIS 10.5.1.

Comment: Attached there is an image with the polygons being created. I want the area of the bigger polygon to be selected. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Erase tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) ; [tutorial on use](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014010) (note that you need an advanced licence).

If you don't have the right licence you could follow this [workaround](https://www.wwu.edu/huxley/spatial/tut/erase.htm).

If you prefer to install other software better than using a workaround you could :

- Use the free version of [ET GeoWizards](https://www.ian-ko.com/ETGeoWizards.html). it offer a similar tool
  and work well with ArcMap (the free version have some limitations :
  some tool are not available or have a feature number limit but the
  erase tool seem to be fully functional)
- Use [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) who have similar tool as ArcMap without licence level
  problem (if you need to switch between ArcMap and QGIS frequently you
  may run in data format compatibility that while perfectly manageable
  could be annoying)

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! I used the Erase tool and it worked!